# Delete duplicate headers in awk

Tags: unix, awk, sed, cat, gawk

I used used `cat` to combine several files and they all have the same headers. Is there anyway I can retain the `1st` occurrence of the header and delete the succeeding headers inside the concatenated file?

Thanks!

Example:

```
FirstName, LastName, Phone, Zip
(data)
(data)
(data)
FirstName, LastName, Phone, Zip
(data)
(data)
(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
sed '1h;2,$G;s/^\(.*\)\n\1$//;/./P;d' filename
```

Comment: @potong: I tried that approach before I posted and couldn't get it to work-- then I saw your comment, tried it again, avoided a couple of pitfalls I'd noticed *after* deciding against that approach, and now it works! Simpler, and one character shorter, good catch.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
cp file1 result
tail -q -n +2 file2 file3 file4 >> result
```

That is, start with the entire contents of file1, then append from the other files starting with line 2 of each.  This way you avoid the need to try to find the extra headers and delete them later.

If you prefer, here's another formulation of the same:

```
head -1 file1 > result
tail -q -n +2 file1 file2 file3 file4 >> result
```

Comment: This worked well, though I forgot to mention that I have 67 files that needs to be concatenated, it would be tedious for me if used it. Thank you BTW.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful and interesting you could upvote it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -e '2,$s/FirstName, LastName, Phone, Zip//g' -e '/^$/d' Yourfile.txt
```

You can replace "FirstName, LastName, Phone, Zip" with whatever header you have. From 2nd line to end of file, it will remove the header patter with , then delete the blank lines with /^$/d'

Comment: Removing the headers worked, although it didn't remove the blank spaces. Thank you BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` version.  It will skipp all line with `FirstName` except line `1`

```
awk 'NR>1 && /^FirstName/ {next}1' file
FirstName, LastName, Phone, Zip
(data)
(data)
(data)
(data)
(data)
(data)
```

If the header line do changing, we need a pattern to follow.

Answer (score 0):

awk way

```
awk '!a[$0];NR==1{a[$0]++}' file
```